# Erro ao gerar schema para o GraphQL com o Graphcool

Tags: graphql

Estou tentando criar um Schema com o Graphcool em uma aplicação Angular. Os tipos são os seguintes:

```
type User @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  name: String!
  email: String! @isUnique
  password: String!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  chats: [Chat!]! @relation(name: "UsersOnChats")
  messages: [Message!]! @relation(name: "MessagesOnUser")
  photo: File @relation(name: "UserPhoto")
}

type Chat @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  title: String
  isGroup: Boolean @defaultValue(value: "false")
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  users: [User!]! @relation(name: "UsersOnChats")
  messages: [Message!]! @relation(name: "MessagesOnChat")
  photo: File @relation(name: "ChatPhoto")
}

type Message @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  text: String!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  sender: User! @relation(name: "MessagesOnUser")
  chat: Chat! @relation(name: "MessagesOnChat")
}

type File @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  secret: String
  name: String
  size: Int
  url: String
  contentType: String
  user: User @relation(name: "UserPhoto")
  chat: Chat @relation(name: "ChatPhoto")
}
```

Ao rodar a aplicação e tentar executar o console para verificar minha mutation, recebo o seguinte erro:

> ERROR Error: "GraphQL error: A unique constraint would be violated on User. Details: Field name = email"

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que já existe um banco de dados criado com estas especificações e, está ocorrendo um erro que fere a diretiva `@isUnique` no campo `email` da model `User`.
Verifique se já não existem usuários inseridos no banco de dados com o mesmo email.

Você pode até tirar temporariamente esta diretiva, somente para passar esta etapa em que ocorre o erro, e então verificar o conteúdo do banco de dados e finalmente fazer as devidas alterações.